# How to design the View layer when developing a Snake game using MVVM in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to develop a snake game in WPF using MVVM , https://github.com/Moore0/SnakeForWPF ,I had trouble designing the View layer

In the View layer I use ListBox as a container, ItemSource is binding to the background data source, set the ListBox's ItemsPanel For UniformGrid, set the DataTemplate to Border for each square, and bind the rows and columns of the board to UniformGrid.Rows and UniformGrid.Columns.

```
<ListBox x:Name="lv"  
        IsEnabled="False" 
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
        VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
        BorderThickness="0" 
        Padding="0"
        ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxForSnakePanelStyle}">
    <ListBox.ItemsSource>
        <!--Entity type design flaws, where multiple parameters must be passed in (but not important)...-->                               
        <MultiBinding Converter="{converters:ItemSourceConverter}">
            <Binding Path="SnakeNodes" />
            <Binding Path="LineX" />
            <Binding Path="LineY" />
            <Binding Path="FoodPoint" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </ListBox.ItemsSource>

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Margin="1" Background="{Binding BlockType,Converter={converters:BlockBrushConverter}}">
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="{Binding LineY}" Columns="{Binding LineX}" Background="{StaticResource BackgroundLightBrush}"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

I think it's rather reluctant to do this. Is there a better way to design the View layer (which is limited to XAML as much as possible)

Comment: Have you considered just using a `Grid` component? Snake has a fixed number of rows/columns so you could hard code this in the layout - since `Grid` also expands to fit the empty space it will work on any size screen. You can bind the background colour of the cell to an array (or something graphical) to determine if the cell is occupied by food/the snake itself (it looks like you already have some paths bound though so you possibly have actual graphics). Your X/Y position on the snake cells could be bound to the column/row position in the grid.

Comment: I'd consider using an `ItemsControl` with an `ItemsPanelTemplate` set to a `UniformGrid`. Binding that to a simple `ObservableCollection` should be dead simple.  You can use some simple properties to convert from row * column to n index within the collection.  This will also allow you to set the number of rows and columns int eh view-model, and bind them.

Comment: The other option is to use an `ItemsControl` inside a `Canvas`.  Then each item would have X and Y coordinate properties that position the element on the canvas.  Thinking about it more, this would probably be my preferred approach. As you are not tracking empty cells, and it allows you to track and position all kinds of items.

Comment: @Charleh Thank you for your answer. I have considered using Grid. If the number of rows is fixed, the problem will be simplified a lot.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a super quick implementation of the `Canvas` based solution I mentioned in comments.  Turning this in to an actual workable game will require more work, of course, but it seems to handle the display very nicely.

The `GameVm` contains the viewmodel for the current game.  It tracks the width and height of the board, as well as any "entities" currently in play.  This includes the different snake-part segments, as well as the food pellets.

The XAML is basically an `ItemsControl` bound to the `Entities` property of the game.  It selects the element's visual based on a template determined by the entity's type.  I just used text characters, but you could easily replace these with images.  The `ItemsControl` is hosted inside a `Canvas`, and the `ContentPresenter` of each item is styled to position it on the `Canvas` based on the entity's `X` and `Y` properties.

I would probably consider changing this to use column / row indexes, rather than "pixel" coordinates, with a `ValueConverter` to convert them to pixels for simplicity.

View models:

```
class MainWindowVm
{
    public MainWindowVm()
    {
        Game = new GameVm(20, 20);
    }

    public GameVm Game { get; }
}

class GameVm : ViewModel
{
    public GameVm(int width, int height)
    {
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
        Entities = new ObservableCollection<GameEntity>();

        Entities.Add(new SnakeHead() { X = 20, Y = 20 });
        Entities.Add(new SnakeBody() { X = 30, Y = 20 });
        Entities.Add(new SnakeBody() { X = 40, Y = 20 });
        Entities.Add(new SnakeTail() { X = 40, Y = 30 });

        Entities.Add(new Food() { X = 0, Y = 0 });
        Entities.Add(new Food() { X = 60, Y = 20 });
        Entities.Add(new Food() { X = 50, Y = 50 });
        Entities.Add(new Food() { X = 10, Y = 80 });

    }

    public ObservableCollection<GameEntity> Entities { get; }

    private int _width;

    public int Width
    {
        get => _width;
        set => SetValue(ref _width, value);
    }

    private int _height;

    public int Height
    {
        get => _height;
        set => SetValue(ref _height, value);
    }
    }

abstract class GameEntity : ViewModel
{
    private int _x;

    public int X
    {
        get => _x;
        set => SetValue(ref _x, value);
    }

    private int _y;

    public int Y
    {
        get => _y;
        set => SetValue(ref _y, value);
    }
}

abstract class SnakeSegment : GameEntity { }

class SnakeBody : SnakeSegment { }

class SnakeHead : SnakeSegment { }

class SnakeTail : SnakeSegment { }

class Food : GameEntity { }
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Snake.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Snake"
        mc:Ignorable="d"

        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowVm />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Game.Entities}">
        <ItemsControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SnakeHead}">
                <TextBlock Text="%" />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SnakeBody}">
                <TextBlock Text="#" />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SnakeTail}">
                <TextBlock Text="." />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Food}">
                <TextBlock Text="O" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Resources>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=X}" />
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=Y}" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

It produces the following output:
[image]